# CakePHP hiding action name in URL, while passing arguments

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, url-routing

I have such a structure:

- example.com / MyController / index / MyGoodPage / maximum/
- example.com / MyController / index / MyBestPage / optimum/
- example.com / MyController / index / MyFancyPage / lowprice/

But I don't want my visitors to see "index" word, because it doesn't give any more information to him/her. I need my URLs like this:

- example.com / MyController / MyGoodPage / maximum/
- example.com / MyController / MyBestPage / optimum/
- example.com / MyController / MyFancyPage / lowprice/

But to do thisin default Cake-way, I need to create seperate hundereds of actions to handle my situation. I don't want to create them all actions, I need to create one action and then show relevant content regarding to `request->params['pass']`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for Routing: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html
and this is actually what is done by default for the core PagesController's `display` method:

```
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

You could do the same for your controller

```
Router::connect('/controller_name/*', array('controller' => 'controller_name', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have already selected an answer, but here is a better one.

`Router::connect('/controller_name/*', array(...));`  as posted above will match anything, so you can no longer access `/controller_name/delete` or any other method.

You should opt for a less greedy route such as `Router::connect('/contorller_name/:something', array(...));` and specify a regex like [maximum|optimum|lowprice] for example.

Doing this you can also specify the `something` to be passed to the controller and it will be available as `$this->request->something`

Comment: Thank you. Adding all of the action arguments into regex wouldn't take too much computation time. What about writing something like this? "Use **display** action, if action name is not action1 or action2"