# CakePHP-Making URL routing rules for a controller

Tags: url, cakephp, routes

I have created a controller "Businesses" and action method call "show_details"

```
function show_details($id = null,$title = null){
         $this->set('Business', $this->Businesses->findById($id));
         $this->render('Business');
    }
```

and the current url will be the `http://127.0.0.1:8080/caketest/businesses/show_details/1/Hattion_National_Bank_Plc`.

But I need to show the Url as `http://127.0.0.1:8080/caketest/Hattion_National_Bank_Plc`
How could I do this? What will be the URL routing rule in routes.php.

I am new to cakePHP so I tried to do this but I failed. your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Check this link-(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070079/remove-action-name-from-url-in-cakephp)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892669/cakephp-hiding-action-name-in-url-while-passing-arguments

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `config/routes.php` and try hitting the url without method name.

```
Router::connect('/businesses/*', array('controller' => 'businesses', 'action' => 'show_details'));
```

Comment: There's no id in the second url, it's not just a route definition. And the route would need to be /* to match the example in the question